# LeakCanary deobfuscation plugin couldn't find any variant with minification

Tags: android, leakcanary

I am trying to enable leakcanary deobfuscation as explained in the next link

[Using LeakCanary with obfuscated apps](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#using-leakcanary-with-obfuscated-apps)

but when i try to sync the gradle i get the next error

> LeakCanary deobfuscation plugin couldn't find any variant with minification enabled.
>           Please make sure that there is at least 1 minified variant in your project.

from what i managed to understand the leakcanary is looking to make sure building in debug but i can't figure out how. I tried to configure the `debuggable true` but it did not seem to help.

It must be basic issue since i can't find any record on google and the implementation notes on leakcanary documentation are very basic

This is my code at the top of gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
// LeakCanary plugin should be added after android application or android library plugin
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.leakcanary.deobfuscation'

leakCanary {
    // LeakCanary needs to know which variants have obfuscation turned on
    filterObfuscatedVariants { variant ->
        variant.name == "debug"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
```

This is my code at the `dependencies`

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'
```

Comment: Is your application obfuscated? If yes can you share the configuration for that, and even maybe file an issue on the project with a sample project that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably related with this LeakCanary issue:
https://github.com/square/leakcanary/pull/1762

Looks like will be fixed in Leak Canary 2.3

Got same issue after tried to switch to Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.1